# Loop to count the number of times a specific letter occurs in a string of letters

Tags: vba, for-loop

This is my first time using VBA and I'm having trouble finding a solution using `FOR` loops to count how many times a specific letter (entered by user) is in the string (entered by user).

Below I have what I have so I've found other solutions but they don't seem to utilize to `FOR` loop.

If anyone has any suggestions that'd be awesome.

```
Sub Week3()
    Dim userInput As String
    Dim letterSearched As String
    Dim counter As Long
    Dim occurances As Long
    
    userInput = InputBox("type letters")
    letterSearched = InputBox("type letter to be searched")
    occurances = 0
    
    For counter = 1 To Len(userInput)
        If (InStr(counter, userInput, letterSearched)) > 0 Then
            occurances = occurances + 1
        Else
            occurances = occurances
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox (occurances)
End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need a loop. Use `Replace` and compare the length of the string prior to and after replacement. Is your requirement to specifically use a loop?

Comment: Sorry. Just saw your comment. Would you like to post it as an answer? I can delete mine @BigBen

Answer (score 2):

No need to use a loop. Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim Mytext As String
    Dim SearchText As String
    
    Mytext = "Sample Text"
    SearchText = "e"
    
    MsgBox Len(Mytext) - Len(Replace(Mytext, SearchText, ""))
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

> Yea I saw that solution but I'm supposed to implement a FOR loop – John Orsa 4 mins ago

Is this what you are trying?

Do not use `InStr`. Use `Mid`

```
For counter = 1 To Len(userInput)
    If Mid(userInput, counter, 1) = letterSearched Then occurances = occurances + 1
Next
```

**Note:** If you want this not to be **case sensitive** then try this

```
For counter = 1 To Len(userInput)
    If Mid(UCase(userInput), counter, 1) = UCase(letterSearched) Then occurances = occurances + 1
Next
```